# How to pass a query as parameter to a bash function that uses it to make queries?

Tags: mysql, bash, function, parameters

I need to update some values in a bunch of databases, since i must connect several times i came with this solution.
The idea is to manipulate external sql files into variables, and pass them to a function that makes the connection and gets the result.
Also there are some hardcoded sql scripts that collect some data via the same function. 
All of this is just the preparation for a final query (consulta2.sql) that must change some statuses depending on the LIMIT of the query.

```
consulta1=$(<consulta1.sql);
consulta2=$(<consulta2.sql);

#INSIDE LOOP------------------------------------

sqlconnection () {
        local q="$*"
        local result=$(mysql -NB -u"user" -p"pass" -h"${domain}"  -D"${sala}" -P${port_db} -e\"${q}\")
        echo "${result}"
    }

qs1="SELECT numero FROM configuracion WHERE clave LIKE 'cantidad_tarjeta_servicio'"
    sqlconnection "$qs1"
    max_service_cards=$*
echo "    - Cantidad Tarjetas Servicio Maxima = ${max_service_cards}." | tee -a ${output}

qs2="SELECT count(*) FROM tarjeta WHERE id_tipo_tarjeta IN (3,4)"
    actual_service_cards=$(sqlconnection "$qs2")
    echo "    - Cantidad Tarjetas Servicio Presentes = ${actual_service_cards}." | tee -a ${output}
```

Contents of .sql scripts

```
-- Consulta1.sql:

DELETE m FROM movimiento AS m 
    INNER JOIN tarjeta AS t ON m.nro_tarjeta = t.nro_tarjeta
WHERE m.tipo_movimiento = 17 AND t.nro_tarjeta IN(3,4);

-- Consulta2.sql:
START TRANSACTION;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS cambioTipoTarjeta;

UPDATE tarjeta t SET t.id_tipo_tarjeta = 5 
WHERE t.nro_tarjeta IN (
    SELECT nro_tarjeta
    WHERE id_tipo_tarjeta IN(3,4)
) AND nro_tarjeta NOT IN (

    SELECT DISTINCT nro_tarjeta FROM ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT m.nro_tarjeta, m.fecha_hora_im
        FROM movimiento m
        WHERE m.fecha_hora_im IN (
            SELECT MAX(m2.fecha_hora_im)
            FROM movimiento m2
            INNER JOIN tarjeta t ON m2.nro_tarjeta = t.nro_tarjeta
            WHERE t.id_tipo_tarjeta IN(3,4) AND m2.tipo_movimiento=4 AND m.nro_tarjeta = m2.nro_tarjeta)
        ORDER BY 2 DESC
 N 
    ) AS tarjetas_sobrantes
);

COMMIT;
```

This is what i get:

```
posadas1:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"DELETE m FROM movimiento AS m INNER JOIN tarjeta AS t ON m.nro_tarjeta = t.nro_' at line 1

Limpieza de Movimientos [0 = OK]: 0.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT numero FROM configuracion WHERE clave='cantidad_tarjeta_servicio'"' at line 1

    - Cantidad Tarjetas Servicio Maxima = 0.
```

This is also another approach i took (full code):

```
#!/bin/bash
config="limpiador_local.conf";
consulta1=$(<consulta1.sql);
consulta2=$(<consulta2.sql);
consulta_procesada="consulta2_test.sql";
current_datetime="$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)";
output="output.log";

echo "Programa ejecutado con configuracion: $config  timestamp: ${current_datetime}" | tee -a ${output}

while read A ; do
    sala=$(echo "$A" | awk -F" " '{print $1}');
    domain=$(echo "$A" | awk -F" " '{print $2}');
    port_db=$(echo "$A" | awk -F" " '{print $3}');

    sqlconnection () {
        local q="$*"
        echo ${q}
        local result=$(mysql -NB -u"user" -p"pass" -h"${domain}"  -D"${sala}" -P${port_db} -e "${q}")
        echo "${result}"
    }
    #conexion=$(mysql --host="${domain}" --user="crucijuegos" --password="cruci00" --database="${sala}" --port=${port_db});
    #conexion=$(mysql -u "crucijuegos" -pcruci00 -D"${sala}");

    echo
    echo "${sala}:" | tee -a ${output}

    sqlconnection ${consulta1}
    echo "Limpieza de Movimientos [0 = OK]: $?."

    qs1="SELECT numero FROM configuracion WHERE clave='cantidad_tarjeta_servicio'"
    max_service_cards=$(sqlconnection $qs1)
    echo "    - Cantidad Tarjetas Servicio Maxima = ${max_service_cards}." | tee -a ${output}
    exit
    qs2="SELECT count(*) FROM tarjeta WHERE id_tipo_tarjeta IN (3,4)"
    actual_service_cards=$(sqlconnection $qs2)
    echo "    - Cantidad Tarjetas Servicio Presentes = ${actual_service_cards}." | tee -a ${output}

    if [[ ${actual_service_cards} > ${max_service_cards} ]] ; then
        sed -e "s/ N /        LIMIT ${max_service_cards}/" consulta2.sql | tee ${consulta_procesada} | tee -a ${output}
        exit
        echo "    [Atencion] Se anularon tarjetas sobrantes." | tee -a ${output}
    else
        echo "    No se realizaron cambios." | tee -a ${output}
    fi

done < $config;

echo "________terminado________";
```

But it also gives:

```
Programa ejecutado con configuracion: limpiador_local.conf  timestamp: 20190905-1534

posadas1:
DELETE m FROM movimiento AS m INNER JOIN tarjeta AS t ON m.nro_tarjeta = t.nro_tarjeta WHERE m.tipo_movimiento = 17 AND t.nro_tarjeta IN(3,4);

Limpieza de Movimientos [0 = OK]: 0.
    - Cantidad Tarjetas Servicio Maxima = SELECT numero FROM configuracion WHERE clave='cantidad_tarjeta_servicio'.
```

Comment: Your errors do not match the code you provided .. 1) there is no delete statement .. And 2)  I see a `WHERE clave LIKE 'cantidad_tarjeta_servicio'` but no `clave='cantidad_tarjeta_servicio'` in the code

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the content of the sql scripts, editing

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the error message clear enough?

```
>mysql -uitsme -e '"SELECT 1"'
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"select 1"' at line 1

>mysql -uitsme -e"select 1"
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but i didn't got your point. I'm trying to pass queries taken from both files and hardcoded as parameters to a connection fuction. Then take the result (wich is always one value or none).
I need those values to "dynamize" the LIMIT of "consulta2", the main query of this script.